# Null in header breaks response

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, google-chrome, iis-7.5

I have a website written in c# asp.net mvc.
Occasionally I get a strange error when requesting any given page. The has only been seen i the Chrome browser so far. I can usually provoke the error by browsing to a page, then quickly request a different page and the back to the first page again. When chrome requests the first page for the second time, the page is returned as follows:

```
nullHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.1
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 29 Dec 2015 09:30:49 GMT
Content-Length: 31679

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="da" data-country="da-DK">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

The html is the correct html for the page, but is not rendered as html, but as text.
I assume it is because of the null in the header: nullHTTP/1.1 200 OK.
But I don't get, why this null text is prepended to the header.

Any ideas?
Best regards
Peter

Comment: Could you provide some context to this problem? Is there any custom code that could interfere with the HTTP headers some way?

Comment: We are using Sitecore 7.2 and are not modifying the Headers in custom code.

Comment: this to me looks more like a bug in the application/modules you are running where they are doing a "Response.Write" on the buffer. That or an extension in the browser?. have you tried capturing the response using Fiddler to see if that null is actually coming from the server (or a chrome extension)?